# Android: Peculiar sms sending

Tags: android, sms, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I'm quite new to android development and opening the logcat while starting a Google Nexus 5 on Genymotion I noticed those peculiar messages:

```
09-05 16:31:38.783   838  1492 V OmtpMessageSender: Sending BINARY sms 'Activate:dt=15' to 122:1808
09-05 16:31:38.807   141   285 D baseband-sms: newsms
09-05 16:31:38.807   141   285 D baseband-sms: sender:(N/A)
09-05 16:31:38.807   141   285 D baseband-sms: receiver:122
09-05 16:31:45.825   141   285 D baseband-sms: index:1/1
09-05 16:31:45.825   141   285 D baseband-sms: txt:'FQKf.Σ:etΔ#W'
09-05 16:45:24.930   765   765 D VvmStatusSmsFetcher: Request SMS successfully sent
```

It seems like a message is automatically sent. It happen every minute since the virtual machine start up. I've tried to google it but I couldn't find anything. I know it's nothing important but it got me curious.

Answer (score 0):

a little late for the party but this possibly will help someone.

The idea is that that SMS is related to Visual Voicemail options (it being ON)[1]. In some cases people attribute it to Hangouts [2] (probably utilized the voicemail option while using Hangouts).

In order to not see it you must disable the Visual Voicemail option[1]. It is worth mentioning that that is an option in the settings app for some OS versions and in the Phone application in others. When looking for how to disable it look it up with your corresponding Android OS, it differs from version to version. In our case it was in the Phone application's settings.

We encountered this behavior with a simple Android AVD Emulator x86 API 27 (the radio buffer in logcat indicated that it was being sent).

Best regards!

[1] https://theinformr.com/answers/activate-dt-15-means-what-8398/

[2] https://support.google.com/hangouts/forum/AAAAfpFnBZ8MgeUrR6JeC8